# Flash, Java, Unity plugin install penetration?

Tags: flash, java, unity, browser-based-games

Is there data on how many users have Flash, Java, or Unity plugins installed?

Comment: Remember that `penetration` is a less useful measure than `penetration + (1 - penetration) * conversion`.

Comment: Equation in word form for posterity: What matters is how many people will use a plugin to view my content, either because they already had it or converted to it just to see my content.

Answer (score 4):

This website extrapolates from a panel of some sort:

http://www.riastats.com/

Bottom line as of posting this:

- Flash: 97%
- Silverlight: 70%
- Java: 75%

Comment: Silverlight 70%? I find that difficult to believe.

Comment: Mail RIA stats then...

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned Flash, Java and Silverlight. Sadly there are no official numbers for Unity I'm aware of. In a rather old [blog post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2008/03/31/thoughts-on-browser-plugin-penetration/) they talk about ~1% pre-installed user base. This [article over at Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AlistairDoulin/20110121/6847/Is_There_A_Unity_Penetration_Issue.php) also assumes 1% penetration. Although the conversion seems to be rather high (people willing to install the plugin).

User base might also increase with gaming platforms like [Kongregate supporting Unity Web-Games](http://www.kongregate.com/unity_game_contest).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Adobe Flash website, [Flash Player Version Penetration](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html), it's about 99-98% in most markets.

Java is also pretty ubiquitous. Unity is less frequently found, however the installer is inline and quite small in most cases.